# npm start Error while parsing JSON - Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: reactjs

When I do npm start it says
/opt/service/semantic/dist/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.woff2: /opt/service/semantic/package.json: Error while parsing JSON - Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: What does your `package.json` file look like?

Comment: It's empty. I've 2 package.josn one in root other one in semantics which is used by docker.